# Scala libraries for a GUI with vector graphics

Tags: swing, scala, user-interface, vector-graphics, scalafx

If I wanted to create a "good old" desktop GUI program with some basic *selectable* vector graphics (arrows, colored boxes, text) to show mostly text and some diagrams (no need for 3D or particles, etc.) that then can be edited by the user, which Scala library would I use, and why? I'd want to build a tool for something similar to drawing diagrams.

Mostly I don't want to use things like D3.js or other web SVG stuff because it is painfully slow and can't show the amounts of content I want it to. But if there are exceptional advantages by using, say, Scala.js, for this purpose, it could be still of interest if there are no better means.

Alternatively, someone can point me to where this had been discussed? Did not find anything on Google or here.

Comment: Added the intention about editing the graphics, too. Many libraries can draw on a canvas, but not all seem to "remember" those elements or allow the user to later manipulate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scala-Swing is a wrapper for Java Swing which is quite nice. As you may know, below Swing lies Java2D, so you will most likely want to look for Java2D based libraries. There aren't that many for Scala that I'm aware of, but more for Java (which you can easily use).

- [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) and [scala-chart](https://github.com/wookietreiber/scala-chart) - more for charting
- [JGraph](https://github.com/jgraph/jgraphx)
- [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/)
- [Processing](http://processing.org/) might have some libraries for your use case
- [JHotDraw](http://www.randelshofer.ch/oop/jhotdraw/) - not sure it's still maintained
- [NetBeans](https://platform.netbeans.org/graph/) - not sure it's still maintained
- [Prefuse](http://prefuse.org/gallery/)

And of course, if it's simple enough, there is nothing wrong with using Java2D directly.

Comment: Thanks. I am surprised, though. One thing I heard is that Oracle has left Swing behind and now only supports JavaFX. How will this affect Java2D?

Comment: I'm not a JavaFX expert. OpenJFX is not yet available for my platform (Debian 8 "testing", not to even speak about Debian stable); so I think for cross-platform code, Swing and Java2D are still the way to go. If you look at the [architecture of JavaFX](http://www.slideshare.net/boulderjug/introduction-to-javafx-20), you'll note that it uses Java2D beneath, so I would expect that you can use Java2D and JFX together. Also there are bridges with Swing.

Comment: To be honest, I am not very impressed about GUI development options with Scala (if excluding the Java libraries, naturally). As there seems no better answer coming along, I am willing to give you the "answer" badge if you could maybe quickly comment on why you did not recommend ScalaFX? Is that simply because you don't know/have access to JavaFX (and, therefore, ScalaFX) or are there some other reasons?

Comment: Yes, I'm also not impressed. Sadly, corporate world seems to think we all want to click around in a browser. I currently have no Java 8 / OpenJFX installation, so I cannot comment on ScalaFX either. I have heard good things, but from a FLOSS and cross platform point of view I'm not considering it right now.